# Eclipse Dynamic Web Project with Maven Integration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I am trying to make a web **Dynamic Web Project** in eclipse, and I want it to also be supported by **Maven**. But as far as I can see, an Eclipse project can be either a Maven project *or* a **Dynamic Web Project**. How can I use both?

Comment: When you create a new project using maven, you can choose the archetype you want...just choose webapp and it will come with the web structure...

Comment: @pecci Will it have the web-inf including the web.xml? and will it have the autocompletion for everything, and act just as if it was a Dynamic Web Project?

Comment: @pecci if you want, you can post it in an answer.

Comment: @Victor2748 yes with archetype, it will have everything that you need - WEB-INF and web.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to create dynamic web project with eclipse, create using maven. As suggested, use archetype - maven-archetype-webapp.

You can't use both maven project and dynamic web project simultaneously in eclipse..

Answer (score 2):

Create a Maven project of type war from the command line, and when you use the File -> Import -> Import Existing Maven project menu entry, it will be set up correctly as a dynamic web project (so you do not have to worry about it)